# Horrible TK/Wish Fonts

Tags: 11.04, fonts, gtk

This is how gitk - which is based on TK/wish - looks on my fresh 11.04 installation:

Are there any better fonts that TK/wish can use by default?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install `tk8.5` and then update wish alternative:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tk8.5
$ sudo update-alternatives --config wish
```

Be sure to select `/usr/bin/wish8.5`.

That should do it.

Good luck